# ASP.NET Core - How to handle exception inside a scoped service

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, try-catch, service-provider

I have some repository classes added as scoped service and I retrieve a particular repository using:

```
var rep = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(interface));
```

That's ok... but when I call:

```
rep.Save();
```

Inside, in some validations, I throw Exceptions... And the problem is that **I can't catch this Exception in the call**, like:

```
try 
{
   rep.Save();
}
catch (Excpetion ex)
{
   // unreachable code
}
```

The exception also causes a stop of current running project.

I don't want a global error handler, I just want to catch this exception to determine what should I do right after.

In DI:

```
svc.AddScoped<IExtratoRepository, ExtratoRepository>();
```

[exception in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPaw9.png)

Comment: this does not make sense. If your `rep.Save` is not asynchronous, it should catch the exception fine. If `rep.Save` returns a `Task`, you need to await it, otherwise no exception will be caught. BTW, if that's the case, by a good naming convention, you should append the suffix `Async` (so we have `SaveAsync` method).

Comment: It is not async. It's very weird because the throw crashes my application.

Comment: Try to find out what kind of exception it is. Unless a very critical exception, that's almost impossible.The asp.net core app is not such easy to be crashed and terminated.

Comment: What is the class that is calling `var rep = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(interface));`?  Is there a reason this isn't simply using Constructor Injection and letting ASP.Net resolve the dependency as intended? Is This a Controller accessing it's HttpContext property, or a custom class/service that you've passed an HttpContext to?

Comment: `var rep = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(interface));` is called at controller. `interface` is an EF repository class. I register `svc.AddScoped<interface, classimplentsinterface>();` and retrive the instance in `var rep = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(interface));`. When I call `rep.Save(); `it works, but when I try to control the method with exceptions, it doesn't work and it stops Visual Studio from debugging.